# Accessing a fragment from MainActivity return null (can not call fragment methods)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have googled everything during a day about the subject and nothing seems to work around for my project. I have added a viewpager to my main activity. There is two fragments attached to it thanks to a page adapter. I initialized everything on the OnCreate method from my main activity. The view pager work well. The problem is when I want to access from my MainActivity the textviews included in my fragments. I created a Set method in each fragment which modify the textviews accordingly to the arguments. So in order to call this method from my MainActivity I have to instantiate the fragments on my MainActivity and the problem is that this line of code return null and the fragments can not be instantiated. Here is the code used for testing this purpose.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
  private SecondActivitySwipeAdapter adapterViewPager;
  private FirstFragmentSwipe fragment1;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");

      setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_test);

      ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
      adapterViewPager = new SecondActivitySwipeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
      vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

      fragment1 = (FirstFragmentSwipe) adapterViewPager.getRegisteredFragment(vpPager.getCurrentItem());

      fragment1.setTextViews(1,2,3,4,5);
  }
 ...
}
```

**SecondActivitySwipeAdapter**

```
public class SecondActivitySwipeAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
private static int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

public SecondActivitySwipeAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
}

// Returns total number of pages
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_ITEMS;
}

// Returns the fragment to display for that page
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return FirstFragmentSwipe.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return SecondFragmentSwipe.newInstance();
        default:
            return null;
    }

}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    registeredFragments.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
    return registeredFragments.get(position);

}
}
```

**FirstFragmentSwipe**

```
public class FirstFragmentSwipe extends Fragment {

private TextView avg1;
private TextView avg2;
private TextView avg3;
private TextView avg4;
private TextView avg5;

public static FirstFragmentSwipe newInstance(){
    return new FirstFragmentSwipe();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipelayout1, container, false);

    avg1 = view.findViewById(R.id.pwrAvgNmbview1);
    avg2 = view.findViewById(R.id.pwrAvgNmbview2);
    avg3 = view.findViewById(R.id.pwrAvgNmbview3);
    avg4 = view.findViewById(R.id.pwrAvgNmbview4);
    avg5 = view.findViewById(R.id.pwrAvgNmbview5);

    return view;
}

public void setTextViews(int avg1, int avg2, int avg3, int avg4, int avg5){
    this.avg1.setText(Integer.toString(avg1));
    this.avg2.setText(Integer.toString(avg2));
    this.avg3.setText(Integer.toString(avg3));
    this.avg4.setText(Integer.toString(avg4));
    this.avg5.setText(Integer.toString(avg5));
}



}
```

The **second fragment** is basically the same as fragment for the moment. I am using some ideas found by googling. The last line of the onCreate method make the app crash. Thanks for you precious help.

Comment: Looks like you're calling `adapterViewPager.getRegisteredFragment()` too soon.  It won't work in onCreate() of the activity, since the fragment is not fully initialized yet.  Just do the first initialization inside the fragment, and use the `adapterViewPager.getRegisteredFragment()` in the activity if you need to update some values later.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here is that `registeredFragments` doesn't have the fragments instantiated yet.
First you can check if fragment1 is null to prevent crashes.

Furthermore you'd rather put initialization methods in `getItem()` of adapter or in `onViewCreated()` of the fragment and do some updates in later lifecycle methods if needed.